# How to work out the percentage of how much someone has paid

Tags: php, math, percentage

I have been trying to [google this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+to+work+out+the+percentage+of+how+much+someone+has+paid&oq=How+to+work+out+the+percentage+of+how+much+someone+has+paid&aqs=chrome..69i57.205j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for hours but am finding it hard to find the maths to achieve this.

If the total payment is 200 GBP and the user has paid 100 GBP - he has paid 50% of the total.

I am trying to translate this to an algorithm but cannot get the expected result.

I have tried:

```
($total / $paid) * 100;
(($total + $paid) / 100) * 2;
($total - $paid) / 100;
```

But neither of this is giving me 50% when I use 200 as the total payment and 100 as the amount paid. Any help would be appreciated. I'm not very good at maths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
$percent = 100 * $paid/$total;
```

To get the percent value up to two decimal places only, you can use the [`Round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function:

```
$percent = ROUND(100 * $paid/$total, 2);
```

Comment: You are a star! I'm glad some of us are maths qualified on SO! Haha, thanks alot! Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @Jaquarh happy to help :)

Comment: Apologies - had to do something for a bit - accepted now! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple just do this `$percentPaid = $paid/$total * 100;`